# Как менять параметр `slidesToShow:` в `slick slider` в зависимости от размеров страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, адаптивная-верстка, slider, slick.js

Как менять параметр `slidesToShow:` в `slick slider` в зависимости от размеров страницы?

Comment: Экстрасенсы в отпуске. Код в студию.

Comment: `breakpoint` у slick есть, создаете их и в них перезаписываете `slidesToShow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации написано:

```
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024, // размер экрана 1024
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3, // тут меняем slidesToShow
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600, // размер экрана 600
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2, // тут меняем slidesToShow
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480, // размер экрана 480
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1, // тут меняем slidesToShow
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```